# Reorder list containing lists into a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a variable of type `List<Item>` where item looks like this:

```
class Item {
    List<Integer> customerId;
}
```

I want to reorder this as `Map<Integer, List<Item>>` where the key is the customerId, and then the value is the list of all items that have that customer id.

This is easily done with two for loops, iterating through the list of items, and for each item iterating through the list of customers.

Is there any way to do this differently, maybe in a more compact way, with Java streams?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Map.Entry for each combination of customer id and Item, and then use `groupingBy`

```
Map<Integer,List<Item>> result = list.stream()
           .flatMap(item->item.getCustomerId()
                   .stream()
                   .map(id->Map.<Integer,Item>entry(id,item)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
Map<Integer, List<Item>> res = list.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getCustomerId()
                       .stream()
                       .map(id -> new SimpleEntry<Integer, Item>(id, e)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k.getKey(),
            Collectors.mapping(v -> v.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```